# How do I search git history for a disappeared line?

Tags: git

I need to search the history of a specific file in a git repository to find a line that is gone.  The commit message will not have any relevant text to search on.  What command do I use?

Further details: this is the history of my todo list out of our non-stellar task tracking software.  I've been keeping it for two years because there's just not enough information kept for me in the software.  My commit messages usually have only the task ids, unfortunately, and what I need to do is find a closed task by subject, not by number.  Yes, the real solution is better task tracking software, but that is completely out of my hands.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

This is a job for the pickaxe!

From the git-log manpage:

> `-S<string>`
>
> Look for differences that introduce or remove an instance of `<string>`. Note that this is different than the string simply appearing in diff output; see the pickaxe entry in gitdiffcore(7) for more details.

You can of course use further options to narrow it down, for example:

```
git log -Sfoobar --since=2008.1.1 --until=2009.1.1 -- path_containing_change
```

There is also:

> `-G<regex>`
>
> Look for differences whose patch text contains added/removed lines that match .
> To illustrate the difference between -S --pickaxe-regex and -G, consider a commit with the following diff in the same file:
>
> `+    return frotz(nitfol, two->ptr, 1, 0);`
>
> `...`
>
> `-    hit = frotz(nitfol, mf2.ptr, 1, 0);`
>
> While `git log -G"frotz\(nitfol"` will show this commit, `git log -S"frotz\(nitfol" --pickaxe-regex` will not (because the number of occurrences of that string did not change).

Comment: I feel like this feature alone should convert people to git. +1

Comment: This seems awesome, but how does the path_containing_change part work? When I add it I don't get any results but without it I see the relevant commits.

Comment: @Ibrahim Possibly a bug... I see the same behavior you do. I do usually test things, but this was two years ago so I don't remember for sure if I tested it or not, since going by the normal syntax for git-log (and the man page), I'd expect it to work. In general adding a path argument like that restricts it to commits which affected that path.

Comment: Oh I'm bad at reading :/ path_containing_change is supposed to refer to the file that you want to look for changes in. It works as expected for me.

Comment: This is amazing!  This is what worked for me: `git log -GcountryCodesArray --since=2013.2.13 --until=2013.3.14 -- application/modules/default/`

Comment: @Ryan I like that option too, docs for `git log -G`: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--Gltregexgt. Specifically note that you can use quotes if you're looking for special chars: `git log -G"Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/A"`

Comment: Does this search all branches?

Answer (score 0):

How about `git log --stat | grep 'filename'` to begin narrowing it down?

Comment: I see no indication that the OP knows the filename. Good approach in general, though. Of course, you can just do `git log filename`.