# git history of a source line

Tags: git, version-control

I've been looking into git diff and git log options to find a way to trace a given source code line history in the repo (branches, authors, commit messages, etc.) but i don't see anything like this.

Are there third-party git tools that can accomplish this?

Comment: Can this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700140/how-do-i-search-git-history-for-a-disappeared-line

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `git blame`.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/8436707/236871 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/8436006/236871

Comment: `git blame` tells you who's responsible for each line in a given (usually current) incarnation of a file.  But it doesn't tell you how a given line changed over time, which is not wholly unreasonable since the line might move around files, etc.  The problem is 'what constitutes the same line in two different versions of the file.

Answer (score 0):

you want

```
git blame
```

If the line of code came from another file at some point in history and you want to track that, you can

```
git blame -M
```

Comment: I think what he wants is to be able to look at multiple git blames, essentially. I.e. find a list of commits where a specific line changed.