# How do I use Git to see the state history of a specific line(specified by a stack trace) in specific file?

Tags: git

I want to come back to [List all the versions of a given line number in the GIT history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785265/list-all-the-versions-of-a-given-line-number-in-the-git-history), closed six years ago, but not answered satisfactorily. I want to see the state history of specific line in a specific file. (The line is specified by a stack trace, so I just want to find out, which revisions are fitting to this stack trace.) git log -L is providing diffs, I do not want to see. git blame refers only to one revision, so I would have to write a script, checking every single commit. I think, there must be a simpler solution.

Comment: In general, the question isn't well defined. Do you want the history of a particular line *number* (which could change based on the addition or deletion of lines before it), or the history of a particular set of characters (whose number could vary through history for the same reasons as above)?

Comment: The question you linked to is closed as a duplicate, of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435343/retrieve-the-commit-log-for-a-specific-line-in-a-file Could you clarify why your question isn't also a duplicate of that?  You mention `git log -L` isn't giving what you want, but I'm not clear how your requirements are different.

Comment: I second this! I think  this will answer your question!

Comment: The specific line in a stack trace is given by the line number. I want to see the contents of  this line for different revisions, no diffs. (If I understand log -L correctly, the report takes into account lines inserted or deleted, but this is not wanted here.)