# Git - Find when a method is removed

Tags: java, git

I am using Git to version control a large java project.

Is it possible to know at which commit a certain method is added or removed from a certain class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I search git history for a disappeared line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700140/how-do-i-search-git-history-for-a-disappeared-line)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can search for the name of the method and you will find the all commits that entered or deleted that string:

```
git log -c -S'methodName' /path/to/file.java
```

Another solution is to find the last commit in which that method exists:

```
$ git blame --reverse START_COMMIT.. file.ext
```

`START_COMMIT` is a commit in which you know for sure the method still exists. You will get a `git blame` output in which you can see the last commit in which that method existed, something like:

```
f590002e (user 2014-01-13 17:27:25 +0000 26)     public void save() {
f590002e (user 2014-01-13 17:27:25 +0000 27)         JPA.em().persist(this);
f590002e (user 2014-01-13 17:27:25 +0000 28)     }
```

Answer (score 5):

Try the "pickaxe" option of git log:

```
git log -S<your-method-name>
```

That will give you all the commits where the string  is added or removed.
Note there is no space after the -S.